# Set ACL while uploading a file to S3 using AWS short term credentials(AWS STS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sts

I am using AWS STS Federation Token to get temporary credentials, with below statement.

```
Statement putStatement = new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
        .withId("TempCreds")
        .withActions(S3Actions.PutObject)
        .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(bucketName, "*"));
```

Now I am able to get temp creds, but when I am uploading a file using `PutObjectRequest`:

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
```

but this is default **PRIVATE ACL**.
Question is how to set PUBLIC ACL?

because when i use below code,

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file)
                        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

the upload fails.

If in the above statement for Getting federation token, I add ACL like below

```
Statement putStatement = new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
        .withId("TempCreds")
        .withActions(S3Actions.PutObject)
        .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(bucketName, "*"))
        .withConditions(S3ConditionFactory.newCannedACLCondition(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

the upload still fails.

So how to set Public ACL when using Short term credentials?

I have given below policy to the IAM User, which is going to generate STS.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1507714071000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:GetFederationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get and does the role you are using with STS have permissions to set ACL on the S3 bucket?

Comment: I have added the policy in question which i have given to the user which is generating STS. Not sure how to give ACL permission in the Policy. Error which I am getting is just "Access Denied", when i am trying to set ACL.

Comment: Do you have access to the bucket via an IAM policy on the user or the group the user is a member of?

Comment: @strongjz yes I do have access to the bucket.

Comment: I'm talking about the Policy attached to the STS creds, what is policy attached to that.

Comment: `code`{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [{
  "Sid": "S3BucketPutPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
  "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"],
  "Condition": {
   "StringEquals": {
    "s3:x-amz-acl": ["public-read"]
   }
  }
 }]
}`code` @strongjz this is the policy attached